# rspec mock external API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a method that amongst other things, calls an outside API that has its own values.

I'd like to mock that call and return a specific response

this is the class/method that is being called :

```
class Transaction
after_save :wallet_to_bank

[...]

def wallet_to_bank
   mangopay_payout_bankwire = MangoPay::PayOut::BankWire.create(
     'AuthorId' => receiver_wallet.provider_user_id,
     'DebitedWalletId' => receiver_wallet.provider_wallet_id,
     'DebitedFunds' => { 'Currency' => currency, 'Amount' => amount },
     'Fees' => { 'Currency' => currency, 'Amount' => 0 },
     'BankAccountId' => receiver_wallet.user.user_bank.provider_id
   )

   update_columns response: mangopay_payout_bankwire

   case mangopay_payout_bankwire['Status']
   when 'CREATED'
     update_attributes(status: :expected,
                    message: I18n.t('api.notifications.wallets_to_bank.success',
                                    transaction_id: mangopay_payout_bankwire['Id']),
                    provider_tansaction_id: mangopay_payout_bankwire['Id'])

     UserMailer.wallet_to_bank(self).deliver
   when 'FAILED'
     update_attributes(status: :failed,
                    message: mangopay_payout_bankwire['ResultCode'],
                    provider_tansaction_id: mangopay_payout_bankwire['Id'])
   end
 end
```

this function is

So I'd like to mock the call to wallet_to_bank, and force the response just for that call

this is what I've tried, but it doesn't work

```
context 'when user has done payin-payout' do
  it 'sends slack ' do
    expect(PaycarSlack.client).to receive(:ping)

   expect(MangoPay::PayOut::BankWire).to receive(:create).and_return(JSON.parse(File.read("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/transaction_response_10.json")))
   transaction = create(:transaction_with_activated_users, amount: 10_000, status: :confirmed, transaction_type: :wallet_to_bank)

 end
end
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you checked out the `web_mock` gem?

Comment: What's the RSpec error? It's not clear from the code shown that your wallet_to_bank method is being called. Try to rearrange your code in the Arrange Act Assert pattern, so allow(MangoPay::Bankwire).to receive...,Transaction.new(*args).wallet_to_bank, expect(whatever your expectation is.)

Comment: It also might be worth considering creating a wrapper class for the MangoPay library with a tailored, easily mockable interface.